# How many spaceships has Doctor Who discovered in London?

Tags: doctor-who

Doctor Who often seems to find spaceships buried under London (For example the Cyberman ship) or perhaps disguised as buildings in London, (I can think of two) or hidden in bedrooms in London.
How many spaceships has Doctor Who discovered in London, in the time period up to and including the 12th Doctor?

Comment: Perhaps the question should be edited with an "As of such-and-such date/season/episode" since future episodes may make any currently acceptable answer invalid otherwise.

Comment: Good point @Lexible . Added. I think this should be a community wiki answer actually...

Comment: Not sure why you're restricting this to London. Both the spaceship upstairs in The Lodger and the Cyberman ship under the department store in Closing Time were in Colchester, for example.

Comment: And, note that many non-British fans of the Doctor may not *know* whether, say, Colchester is considered a part of the London metropolitan area or not.

Comment: @RDFozz Suggesting they should not be the ones to answer?

Comment: To be honest, I thought that Colchester episode was in London.